# jQuery to PHP array

Tags: php, json

I have a script which saves text files of inputs which I need to parse into my database.  I'm using PHP to do the parsing into MySQL, but the text files are not JSON compliant and I'm at a standstill on how to convert this data into something PHP can read as an array.

Given `json_decode()` doesn't work on the text, what would be an option to convert this into an array in PHP so I can take the values from `"id"`, `"p"`, `"m"`, and `"op"` to insert into my database.

Text example inside file (ie: file1.txt) below:

```
jQuery([{"id”:”abcd123”,”p”:”1999.00","m":"1123.00","op":"1332.00"},{"id”:”efgh1234”,”p”:”642.00","m":"829.00","op":"712.40”}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's basically and array with two objects in it. In PHP that would be an associative array.

You should be able to send it to PHP with AJAX or normal for submits.

```
var content = JSON.parse("[{"id”:”abcd123”,”p”:”1999.00","m":"1123.00","op":"1332.00"},{"id”:”efgh1234”,”p”:”642.00","m":"829.00","op":"712.40”}]");
```

Once you send the `content` array to PHP you can manage it however you need to.

Comment: Hi Abraham,Yes, but its not JSON compliant, because of the "jQuery([" at the start and the "]);" at the end, hence the issue and the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the .txt file on server-side, here how to open and parse it:

```
<?php

// An array to fill.
$objArr = [];

// Preparing to open a .txt file located on the server.
$handle = fopen("path-to-file/file1.txt", "r");

// If PHP succeed the opening of the file.
if ($handle) {
  while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

    // If we're on a line having at least one object.
    if( strpos($line,"{") > 0 ){
      $countObjects = substr_count($line, "{");

      // For each objects detected
      for($i=0;$i<$countObjects;$i++){
        $openPos = strpos($line,"{");
        $closePos = strpos($line,"}");

        // Push all objects in an array.
        array_push($objArr, json_encode( substr($line,$openPos,$closePos-$openPos) ) );

        // Remove the processed part of the line.
        $line = substr($line,$closePos);
      }
    }
  }

  // close the file.
  fclose($handle);

  // You now really have an array of json object, instead of a string.
  // use it to pass the values to your DB.

  // Like:
  $id = $objArr[1].id;  // efgh1234

  // Up to you here...
  // ...


} else {
    // error opening the file.
    echo "ERROR opening the .txt file.<br><br>";
    die;
} 

?>
```

**Note** that `path-to-file` is the path from the linux `/`.
it can be just `.` if this PHP script is in the same folder as the .txt file to process.

This is untested, obviously.
Let me know if having trouble.

Comment: I just added something to remove the "processed" part of the string, since `strpos()` returns only the first occurance. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Read in the contents with however you're already doing that and assign the value to a variable

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents (...);
```

Remove the `jQuery(` and `)`.

```
$file_contents = substr($file_contents, 7, -2);
```

Now you can use `json_decode`.

```
$data = json_decode($file_contents, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange way of storing the JSONs. If you can directly store it without the "Jquery(" prefix and ");" suffix, your life would be much easier.

As to your question put in that way, I wouldn't suggest parsing the whole text file, as if your text file contains hundreds or thousands of elements, the parsing would take up time and resources.

A tricky solution would be to omit the initial Jquery( part and the last ); elements:

```
$input = 'jQuery([{"id”:”abcd123”,”p”:”1999.00","m":"1123.00","op":"1332.00"},{"id”:”efgh1234”,”p”:”642.00","m":"829.00","op":"712.40”}]);'

// Those ” are different than " and therefore not accepted in JSON parsing.

$input = str_replace('”', '"', $input);

$omitWord = 'jQuery(';
if(strpos($input,$omitWord) === 0){
    $input = substr_replace($input,"",0,strlen($omitWord));
}

$inputLength = mb_strlen($input);

if($input[$inputLength-1] == ';' && $input[$inputLength-2] == ')'){
    $input = mb_substr($input,0,-2);
}

$itemArray = json_decode($input, true);
```

This would work for the cases when you have jQuery( prefix + ;) suffix or the pure json object. I've added additional checks because your json elements might contain either "jquery(" or ");", which could lead to a potential bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things.
a) Replace the character ” with " . Use str_replace for that
b) Extract the file_contents .I'm assuming you know how to do that. file_get_contents is one call. Can even work with remote links.
c) extract associative array.

```
$out = substr($str,8,-3);
$array = explode(',', $str);
```

The new output will be 
Array ( [0] => {"id":"abcd123" [1] => "p":"1999.00" [2] => "m":"1123.00" [3] => "op":"1332.00"} [4] => {"id":"efgh1234" [5] => "p":"642.00" [6] => "m":"829.00" [7] => "op":"712.40"} )

The rest should be easy enough to process now. There might be better ways also to do this. Did not have time to explore.